# CAnnot upload image after upgrade to 1.1.9.3 Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Maybe you have seen this question before, but I still cannot find a solution after I have upgraded Magento to 1.1.9.3. Can some one explain the solution 3 in this link?
https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-Solutions-to-Different-Problems/td-p/52572

> and in main template that following is not overwritten by another
>   theme.

Where is main template?

Answer (score 0):

Image Button Problem / Not Uploading pictures / Flash Uploader replaced
In latest version the existing flash uploader is now finally replaced.

**Solution 1**  - Delete the following folder `/skins/adminhtml/default/default/media/` or following files in the folder

Solution 2 - If you have CreareSEO module add following to file

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/creareseo/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
```

Between Line 84 and 85 (new line 85)

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is %s.', Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION)); ?>
```

Remove line 97 and insert

```
var <?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?> = new Product.Gallery('<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>', <?php echo $_block->getImageTypesJson() ?>);
```

**Solution 3** - Where themes overwrite header files and will not upgrade / use magento default header

In Admin section: `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml` be sure that following line is there

```
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/uploader.js</script></action>
and in main template that following is not overwritten by another theme. 
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</name></action>
<action method="addJs"><name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</name>
```